# WSGIPath Error while Deploying Django App using AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Django Project on AWS using Elastic Beanstalks. I have tried multiple value changes for WSGIPath. 
But Everytime, I am getting the same Error:

while running 'eb create' from ubuntu terminal:

Error Logs (from Eb logs):

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
mod_wsgi (pid=3005): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/myapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=3005): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/myapp/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/current/app/myapp/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
```

Can someone please explain how this path is picked up and how this can be corrected ?

My Project Structure:

```
.
├── .ebextensions
│   ├── myapp.config
├── .elasticbeanstalk
│   ├── config.yml
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── media
├── abc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── test1_form.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── templates
└── myapp
    ├── constants.py
    ├── test1_form.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── registration_form.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

myapp.config File:

```
option_settings:
        "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python": 
        WSGIPath: "myapp/wsgi.py"
```

config.yml file

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: abc-dev
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: abc
  default_ec2_keyname: abc_eb_key
  default_platform: Python 2.7
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
```

settings.py File:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'
```

myapp/wsgi.py file:

```
import os, sys, inspect

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same error

Comment: @Vlad, yes i got this issue fixed. I have added updated myapp.config file in the answer. See if that works for you. If not, please share your Project Structure, Config Files and the Error Logs( eb logs > logs.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated myapp.config File Which worked:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python": 
    WSGIPath: "myapp/wsgi.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```